# get select option value without form='sg' attribute

Tags: html, validation, select, post, w3c

I have a select option tag in my code, and I would like to get the value of it. I know 2 solution but none of them is w3c valid, and it has to be valid.. I tried these:

```
<form id="carform">
Firstname:<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<select name="carlist" form="carform">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

the problem with this is that w3c validation using 4.01 html and this attribute is not part of it (html5).

I tried this too:

```
<form id="carform">

Firstname:<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">


<select name="carlist">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

but its not valid either. so I wonder how to make it work and valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need the `form` attribute; instead, just put all the form fields inside the `form` element, as you have done in your second attempt. That attempt has some *other* issues, but they are unrelated to the issue of associating a control with a form. They are: lack of `action' attribute; not wrapping`form` element content in a block-level container (if you need to conform to HTML 4.01 for some odd reason; it has strange requirements like this).

Minimally fixed version (just to please validators, not considering usability, functionality, etc.):

```
<form id="carform" action="">
<div>
Firstname:<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">


<select name="carlist">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If I use this I get this error:
The mentioned element("select") is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it.

Comment: @user3351357, no, what you are quoting here is an *explanation* to an error message with the pattern “document type does not allow element X here; missing one of Y start-tag”, and that error does *not* appear if you use my code as-is, just with the required doctype declaration and `title` element before it. The code that you tested is somehow different.